# How to Call Method in LINQ Select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following method:

```
internal void DuplicateGroup(int oldGroupId, int newGroupId) {
    IEnumerable<int> res = (from p in Db.table
                            where p.GroupID == oldGroupId
                            select p.packSizeID);
    foreach (int ps in res)
        Db.table.Add(new entityclass { GroupID = newGroupId, packSizeID = ps });
}
```

The method builds a List from desired IDs then adds new rescords to the same table with newGroupIDs. The question is: is it possible to call method within select?

Comment: If this is Linq to Entities (and I assume it is), then no. You cannot call methods from your code, inside SQL select queries.

Comment: Yes it is Linq to Entities.

Comment: @Franziee so, like @Andei wrote, you cannot call method inside `Select`. EF will not known how to translate it into SQL query. Exceptions are some methods inside `Math` or `SqlFunctions` - these method are known to EF and it knows how to translate them. You can also use ToList() and then make projection, but it will  fetch records into memory.

Comment: What Linq actually does, is it creates an actual SQL "command text", which is sent to the database server, which in turns executes it. Your custom code method is not converted to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in that select no, but in some selects, yes.  It depends on the data source.  LINQ over EF, no, but LINQ over objects, yes.